# How can i configure the public and system thread pool size in ignite

Tags: c++, ignite, in-memory-database

```
<!-- Configure internal thread pool. -->
<!--property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="64"/-->

<!-- Configure system thread pool. -->
<!--property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="24"/-->
```

Here are the two configurations i tried.

Error

```
 Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException:
 Invalid property 'systemThreadPoolSize' of bean class [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration]: 
 Bean property 'systemThreadPoolSize' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter 
 type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

 Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
 Invalid property 'publicThreadPoolSize' of bean class [org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration]: 
 Bean property 'publicThreadPoolSize' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter 
 type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I am trying out the configurations here. https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/v2.0/docs/performance-tips 
Most of them seem to be incorrect. can any also suggest where can i find the property names for xml configurations for performance tuning in FULL_SYNC Mode.

Comment: Please share your full Ignite config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put it in wrong place, you put it inside cache config, while it must be a part of ignite configurations:

```
 <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

....

  <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="100"/>
  <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="100"/>

....

   <property name="cacheConfiguration">
      <list>
          <!-- NOT HERE -->
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Ok i have now placed it under ignite configuration. but the number of thread count for my process is still not increased. Its 48. is there any other configuration for changing the thread pool size.

Comment: Ignite will create more threads when it's needed. Try to send hundreds compute tasks, public pool is used to execute those tasks, ignite will increase its size to handle all sended compute tasks.